# Задача про ловушку. Алгоритм поиска пути

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, поиск

Спроектирован робот который несет бремя из точки A в точку B.

Чтобы протестировать робота была выбрана матрица размером `n x m`, по которой робот должен передвигаться из точки `(0, 0)` к точке `(n, m)`.

Робот имеет два варианта для продвижения, сверху вниз и справа налево.

Если значение поля `i, j` матрицы равно -1, это значит, что там находится ловушка, которая может навредить роботу. Что, в свою очередь, означает, что робот не может наступить на это поле.

Нужно написать функцию которая получает матрицу и вернет `true`, если робот сможет из точки `(0, 0)` дойти до точки  `(n, m)`, а в противоположном случае `false`.

Например

```
A = [
    [0, 0, 0, -1, 0],
    [-1, 0, 0, -1, -1],
    [0, 0, 0, -1, 0],
    [-1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, -1, 0, 0]
]

B = [
    [0, 0, -1],
    [0, -1, -1],
    [-1, -1, 0]
]
```

Робот сможет дойти до конечной  в случае матрицы A, а в случае B не сможет.

```
console.log([
               [0, 0, 0, -1, 0],
               [-1, 0, 0, -1, -1],
               [0, 0, 0, -1, 0],
               [-1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, -1, 0, 0]
            ]);   // true

console.log([
              [0, 0, -1],
              [0, -1, -1],
              [-1, -1, 0]
            ]);  // false

console.log([
              [0, 0, 0], 
              [0, 0, 0], 
              [0, 0, 0]
           ]);     // true

console.log([
              [0, 0, 1], 
              [1, 0, -1], 
              [0, -1, 0]
            ]);  // false
```

Поможете решить задачу?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8

Comment: Обычный dfs, я уже где-то отвечал...

Answer (score 3):

Заведем массив, в котором будем помечать, можно ли дойти до какой-либо определенной клетки и будем его пересчитывать через предыдущие, то есть используем идеи динамического программирования.

Ниже приведено подобие псевдокода:
Будем считать что идем из левого верхнего угла в правый нижний, эта задача аналогична вашей.

```
dp[0][0] = true; //Данная клетка может быть посещена точно, в ней мы находимся изначально.
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
   {
      dp[i][j] = (dp[i - 1][j] | dp[i][j - 1]); 
/*
Данная клетка (i,j) будет обозначена возможной для посещения,
 если клетка сверху или клетка слева может быть посещена.
 В таком случае понятно, что можно прийти в данную. 
Также нужно учитывать, что если мы находимся в клетке (0, i), то она не может быть пересчитана через (-1, i),
с этим нужно справиться, написав несколько ифов. */
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function traverse(matrix, curr_coords = [0, 0]){
  const need_coords = [matrix.length - 1, matrix[0].length - 1]
  // Если мы не на нужной строке и следуящая координата строки != -1, то возварщаем вызов этой функции, со смещенным на 1 номером строки
  if(curr_coords[0] != need_coords[0] || curr_coords[1] != need_coords[1]){
    let can_move_next = false;
    if(curr_coords[0] < need_coords[0] && matrix[curr_coords[0] + 1][curr_coords[1]] != -1){
      can_move_next = traverse(matrix, [curr_coords[0] + 1, curr_coords[1]]) || false
      // Если мы можем пройти из этой точки (т.е. вернулось true) возвращаем его
      if(can_move_next){
        return can_move_next
      }
  } 
  // Если мы не на нужном стобце и следуящая координата столбца != -1, то возварщаем вызов этой функции, со смещенным на 1 номером столбца
    if(curr_coords[1] < need_coords[1] &&  matrix[curr_coords[0]][curr_coords[1] + 1] != -1){
      can_move_next = traverse(matrix, [curr_coords[0], curr_coords[1] + 1]) || false
      // Если мы можем пройти из этой точки (т.е. вернулось true) возвращаем его
      if(can_move_next){
        return can_move_next
      }
    }
    return can_move_next
  }
  // Возвращаем true если мы на нужном месте
  return true
}

//true
const a = [
  [0, 0, 0, -1, 0],
  [-1, 0, 0, -1, -1],
  [0, 0, 0, -1, 0],
  [-1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, -1, 0, 0]
]

//false
const b = [
  [0, 0, -1],
  [0, -1, -1],
  [-1, -1, 0]
]

//true
const c = [ 
  [0, 0, -1], 
  [0, -1, 0], 
  [0, 0, 0] 
]

//true
const d = [
  [0, 0, 0], 
  [0, 0, 0], 
  [0, 0, 0]
]

//false
const e = [
  [0, 0, 1], 
  [1, 0, -1], 
  [0, -1, 0]
]

const f = [[0,0,1],[1,0,0]] 


console.log(traverse(a))
console.log(traverse(b))
console.log(traverse(c))
console.log(traverse(d))
console.log(traverse(e))
console.log(traverse(f))
```

Comment: при матрице const c = [
  [0, 0, -1], 
  [0, -1, 0], 
  [0, 0, 0]
]; путь есть но выводит false!

Comment: Спасибо, исправил, а также добавил примеры не на случайных матрицах, а на матрицах из задания

Comment: Александр Лесив проверьте матрицу [[0,0,1],[1,0,0]] Код выдает ошибку

Comment: @ROBBSTARK, да функция с итеративным подходом действительно, почему-то на не квадратных матрицах выдает ошибку... Но я программист и мне лень, поэтому просто удалю ее и оставлю только рекурсивное решение

Comment: @АлександрЛесив, потому что надо было внимательнее к счетчикам относится, `i` заводился как счетчик по внутреннему массиву, а использовался как счетчик по внешнему.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function solution(x){
    if(x[x.length-1][x[0].length-2]==-1 && x[x.length-2][x[0].length-1]==-1 || x[0][0]==-1){
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

console.log(solution([[0,0,0,-1,0],[-1,0,0,-1,-1],[0,0,0,-1,0],[-1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,-1,0,0]])) //true
console.log(solution([[0,0,-1],[0,-1,-1],[-1,-1,0]])) //false
console.log(solution([[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]])) //true
console.log(solution([[0,0,1],[1,0,-1],[0,-1,0]])) //false
console.log(solution([[-1,-1,-1],[-1,-1,-1],[-1,-1,-1]])) //false
console.log(solution([[0,0,1],[-1,-1]])) //true
console.log(solution([[-1,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]])) //false
```

Comment: если в трех клетках нет -1, еще не значит, что есть путь из начальной клетки в конечную: `solution([[0,0,-1,0,0],[0,0,-1,0,0],[0,0,-1,0,0],[0,0,-1,0,0],[0,0,-1,0,0]])`